# Dynamic height and width for knitr plots

Tags: r, knitr

In knitr, one can specify the size of plot by simply specifying it in the chunk options.

For example:

````
```{r, fig.width=9,fig.height=3}
plot(x)
```
````

I would like to be able to dynamically adjust the figure height and width on the basis of variables in `x`. Let's say that x is a data.frame:

```
x <- data.frame(x=factor(letters[1:3]),y=rnorm(3))
```

For example's sake lets say I would like to adjust fig.height to be equal to `length(unique(x$x))`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can for example  define the width in another chunk, then use it

````
```{r,echo=FALSE}
x <- data.frame(x=factor(letters[1:3]),y=rnorm(3))
len = length(unique(x$x))
```


```{r fig.width=len, fig.height=6}

plot(cars)
```
````

Comment: I like this answer, I just wish there was someway to make knitr look into the current chunk (rather than having to define it previously). I've been playing with "before" hook, trying to see if I can get something out of it. No dice thus far.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I understand that, but `knitr` has to open the graphical device (with an appropriate size) *before* evaluating the chunk, so you have to evaluate the code in a previous chunk in order to use the objects in a latter chunk.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I can't say better than Yihui. Just for me it is a better for readability to set all your parameters in one chunck, for example init.chunck.

Answer (score 20):

I just found a great blog post about this.

Read more [at Michael J Williams' blog](http://michaeljw.com/blog/post/subchunkify/) - I've shamelessly pilfered the code, so more detail there. **Remember to set chunk options to results = "asis".**

Say you want to output a bunch of plots using a loop but you want them to each have different sizes. Define the following function (*again, I'm just copy-pasting here*):

```
subchunkify <- function(g, fig_height=7, fig_width=5) {
  g_deparsed <- paste0(deparse(
    function() {g}
  ), collapse = '')

  sub_chunk <- paste0("
  `","``{r sub_chunk_", floor(runif(1) * 10000), ", fig.height=",
   fig_height, ", fig.width=", fig_width, ", echo=FALSE}",
  "\n(", 
    g_deparsed
    , ")()",
  "\n`","``
  ")

  cat(knitr::knit(text = knitr::knit_expand(text = sub_chunk), quiet = TRUE))
}
```

And use the function like this, defining your own figure sizes:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
g <- ggplot(economics, aes(date, unemploy)) + 
  geom_line()
subchunkify(g, 10, 3)
subchunkify(g, 7, 7)
```
````

Or let the data define the sizes:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
g <- ggplot(economics, aes(date, unemploy)) + 
  geom_line()
for (i in seq(2, 5)) {
  subchunkify(g, i / 2, i)
}
```
````

In the post Michael warns that you must be careful:

> Since we’re using results='asis', if we want to output text or headings or anything else from the chunk, we must use raw HTML, not Markdown, and we must use cat() to do this, not print(). For instance:

```
g <- ggplot(economics, aes(date, unemploy)) + 
  geom_line()

cat('<h2>A Small Square Plot</h2>')
subchunkify(g, 3, 3)
```

Again, not my work... head on over to that [lovely blog post](http://michaeljw.com/blog/post/subchunkify/) for more details. Hope this works for you.

Comment: I needed to modify the last line of the `subchunkify` function so that it reads `cat(trimws(knitr::knit(text = knitr::knit_expand(text = sub_chunk), quiet = TRUE)))`. Then everything worked great.

Comment: This is soooo close, but I can't stomach the additional necessary changes to use the `asis` option.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround this problem, especially if you want to change figure parameter within a loop,

1. Define another chunk, a function which executes the loop
2. Separately define the figure details in the following chunks

   ````
   ```{r, echo=FALSE}
   testFunction <- function (parameter) {
       x <- data.frame(x=c(1:parameter), y=rnorm(parameter))
       g1 <- ggplot(data=x, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
       print(g1)
   }
   ```


   ```{r fig.width=10, fig.height=6}
   testFunction(10)
   ```


   ```{r fig.width=5, fig.height=4}
   testFunction(4)
   ```
   ````